# Intro to c++ and I'm swamped

Tags: cygwin, codeblocks, ifstream, getline, ofstream

I just started an introduction to C++ course on Monday and I feel completely out of my depth. First, they told me to install Crimson editor and Cygwin (to compile files):

Crimson editor won't allow me to do anything (all options seem to be completely greyed out).

Cygwin is similar in that I can open the command prompt from the batch file (as directed by the tutorial file given to the class) but I am unable to do anything from there. I have asked for assistance but have yet to receive a reply, so I have decided to see if I can find assistance online.

After having these issues, I was suggested to use codeblocks from others online which I have an has been working great. The first question I have is will codeblocks be an issue when it comes time to compile/debug files (they have stated that for every assignment that every submission should include a makefile, a makedebug, and will be marked under the following criteria:

> Marking Scheme
>
> You will be graded on the following criteria:
>
> Program compiles without errors 20%
> Correct program execution 20%
> C++ program correctness and style 20%
> Program documentation 20%
> Test plan 20%
> Total 100%

Unfortunately, they have not introduced quite a few of these concepts to us yet (I'm hoping they introduce them shortly as I'm coming to the end of the first section (by which they had said we should be able to complete the first assignment which is to code 4 programs)).

This brings us to the next issue. I am attempting to practice using `while(getline())`, but am running into some issues (again, I have almost 0 experience with programming language and decided to take this class as it was supposed to be an introductory class. Funnily enough, "While" is a concept that will be introduced later in the course but luckily I have a very basic understanding of it from videos online). Below is the code I am attempting to run:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    string docName;
    cout<<"What is the file name you would like to open?"<<endl;
    cin>> docName;

    string s, line;
    ifstream in (string docName);

    while (getline(in, line))
        s+=line+"\n";
    cout << s;

    return 0;
}
```

There is an error here and I am unsure of why I am receiving this error. Additionally, I am having some issue fully understanding 3 aspects of code similar to this:

getline()

ifstream in()

and ofstream out()

As an introduction to strings they used the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ifstream in("Scopy.cpp");
    ofstream out("Scopy2.cpp");
    string s;
    while(getline(in, s))
        out<<s<<"\n";
    return 0;
}
```

and

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ifstream in("FillString.cpp");
    string s, line;
    while(getline(in,line))
        s+= line + "\n";
    cout<< s;
}
```

As you can probably understand I'm a bit overwhelmed by all this. I'm coming to the end of the first section wherein they say we should be able to complete the assignments:

> Write a program that opens a file and counts the whitespace-separated words in that file.
>
> Write a program that opens a (text) file, and displays the contents of that file one line at a time. After a line has been displayed, the program should wait for the user to press the key before displaying the next line in the file.
>
> Write a program that uses two nested for loops and the modulus operator (%) to detect and print the prime numbers from 1 to 10,000. (Prime numbers are natural numbers that are not evenly divisible by any other number except for themselves and one). Display all the primes found.
>
> Write a program that creates an array of 100 string objects. Fill the array by having your program open a (text) file and read one line of the file into each string until you have filled the array. Display the array using the format “line #: ,” where # is the actual line number (you can use the array counter for this value) and  is the stored string.

Would someone could explain these in layman's terms? (I have actually been following NewBoston's tutorial's for C++ which have been incredibly helpful, but I looked ahead to where these are introduced and though I'm on tutorial 20 which is like 3 hours into his nearly 10 hour introductory video, these are introduced at tutorial 68... quite a while away).

Comment: Ideally, please aim to ask about one thing at a time. We have a close reason of "too broad" here, and readers may vote for that hold status on the basis that the question would be more answerable, or more useful for other readers, if it is narrowed down a bit.

Answer (score 1):

First suggestion: I have the impression that your teacher is taking inspiration and some code from

Thinking in C++, 2nd Edition, Volume 1 by Bruce Eckel

available from here:

https://www.mindviewllc.com/quicklinks/
https://archive.org/details/TICPP2ndEdVolOne

I suggest you to read it; I found it very good to explain the concept of C++

Second suggestion: Cygwin comes with a `Cygwin Terminal` icon. Use it to launch the bash command interpreter. Be sure also to install the `gcc-g++` package to compile the code.

The error message from the compiler is telling you that it does not match
the arguments of getline:

```
$ g++ prova0.cpp -o prova0
prova0.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
prova0.cpp:17:30: error: no matching function for call to ‘getline(std::ifstream (&)(std::string), std::string&)’
     while (getline (in, line ) )
                              ^
```

The problem in the code is here

```
 ifstream in (string docName);
```

where you are defining the stream `in`
Compare it with the other code

```
ifstream in("Scopy.cpp");
```

there is a word `string` too much.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. First, sorry about the multiple questions (I hadn’t realized there was a rule for the number of questions one could ask in a post). Second, this is not regarding homework (though I will need to use these concepts in my assignments), so I apologize if it seemed as though I were fishing for answers. Regarding your first suggestion, yes, we are using Eckel’s book, however I am struggling with the beginning (hence the questions).

Comment: Regarding your other suggestions, I will attempt to bash command interpreter (though I have no idea what that is, as I said this is the introductory class and I have almost no experience with any of this) in Cygwin tomorrow as well as removing the string. Finally, as it seems you’re knowledgeable regarding materials, are there any other books you would suggest? I’m also reading accelerated c++ but I feel as though many of these books assume you have a core understanding of C, thus they feel bit difficult to grasp for someone as inexperienced as I. Anyways, thanks again. Much appreciated.

Comment: Bash is a command interpreter. It is one of the most used under Unix/Linux, usually the default one. As Cygwin it is a Unix enviroment for Windows any bash tutorial around is fine. The reason for single question is that before asking, you can check if someone already asked something similar in the past.